# Guidance required for code generation tool

Tags: qt, code-generation

I am interested to write a GUI based tool which would generate code in return. Something similar to VB GUI interface or Xcode's Interface Builder. I am going to use QT tookkit which is cross platform.

Can you help me to point out some resources which could be helpful to make such tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Qt creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) comes with an integrated UI Designer. The [designer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-manual.html) can be used stand alone or [integrated into Visual Studio](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in) as well.

Comment: I have to write the GUI similar to QT designer or something which would generate code behind. I need help how to start it out

Comment: Why can't you use QT Designer? Is the the question: how do I write a QT Designer clone? If so I cannot help you since that is a question that is not specific enough to be answerable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/faq for details.